# What property implies finitely generated-ness of global sections as an algebra?

Tags: schemes

It is well-known that if $ X $ is a proper scheme over a ring $ A $, the global sections $ \mathcal{O}_{X} ( X ) $ of $ X $ are integral over $ A $. If $ X $ is moreover projective over $ A $, the global sections form a finitely generated *module* over $ A   $.

We also know that the property of being finitely generated as a module is equivalent to being integral and being finite generated as an algebra.   The natural question is then the following:

Is there some weaker property $ P $ of schemes such that being projective implies being $ P $ and $ X $ having $ P $ guarantees that the global sections of $ X $ are finitely generated over   $  A $ as an algebra?